# Can't validate AVRO schema with optional value

Tags: validation, schema, avro

I have this AVRO schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SelectActiveApp",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "eventName",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "eventData",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "EventData",
        "fields": [
               {
            "name": "appId",
           "type": ["null", "string"],
            "default": null
          }
          ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when I try to validate some data, this works:

```
{
  "eventName": "active-app-selected",
  "eventData": {
    "appId": null
  },
}
```

But this is not working!

```
{
  "eventName": "active-app-selected",
  "eventData": {
    "appId": "any string"
  },
}
```

Why? I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this

```
 {
  "eventName": "active-app-selected",
  "eventData": {
    "appId": { "string": "some string"}
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! But it's not what I want to achieve. I've seen that Avro supports nullable fields via an extension (basically you should use "string*" instead of "string", but since it it an extension, I can't use this syntax on GCloud I suppose. I ended up using a "proto3" schema.